# Taking images from camera without user interaction?

Tags: iphone, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, zooming

I am creating an app in which, as soon as the `UIImagePickerController` loads (i.e. the camera view), it should start taking pictures without any click and store images in an array. How can I do this without clicking on the "shoot" button?

In reference library, `UIImagePickerController` contains an instance method, `-takePicture`. Can somebody tell me if this function will do the trick, if I call it through timer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`-takePicture` should do the trick in deed. You have to provider a custom UI for the camera controls, because otherwise (for me) it doesn't work. Check out the developer documentation in Xcode and search for *takePicture*. The method description has everything you need.

Comment: thnaks andres, then i think i have to upgarade os 3.1

Comment: Yes, you would have to upgrade to OS 3.1. If you want to do it without having to upgrade, you can use a screengrab method, such as `CGImageRef cgScreen = UIGetScreenImage();`, which will get you an image of what is currently being displayed on the iphone screen.

Comment: I assume you are trying the same thing I am. TakePicture simply allows programmatic access to what was the take picture button. It doesnt allow repeated photo taking as far as I know which is a shame. The CGImageRef idea works great BUT it is likely to be rejected by the App Store